# Converting tabs to spaces on CSS

Tags: css, tabs, spaces, text-indent

I'm having a spot of trouble working out how to change all indentations in my CSS code to spaces rather than tabs. Is there any way I can do this all in one? Or do I have to go through line by line, converting them.

Comment: Almost every text editor has a feature that converts tabs to spaces...

Comment: How do you get to that feature? I'm very new to CSS.

Comment: This has nothing to do with CSS. How do you write your code? Which editor/IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to do it all once, You can automatically indent the files by using a CSS beautifier.

It is availible for all major IDE's and Editors (Atom, Brackets, Visual Studio Code etc.)

And you can change the settings of the beautifier from tabs to spaces.